# PostgreSQL: Unable to assign "SELECT" query to variable within function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to assign a "SELECT" query to specific variable for further usage, but getting an error. The details as shown below with an example.

Example: Creating function with two parameters columnname and relationname and want to retrieve the rows accordingly.

--Function

```
create or replace function function1(columnname varchar,relationname varchar)
returns setof record as
$body$

declare
    --Declaration of variables used ahead
    str varchar;
    additionalcolumn varchar;
    grp varchar;
    selectquery varchar;
begin
    --IF condition to check "columnname" for first condition.
    if columnname='PhoneNo2' then
         str:='PhoneNo2';
         additionalcolumn:='Tower'||','||'State'||','||'Country';
         grp:='PhoneNo1'||','||columnname; 

          .
          . -- Other conditions 
          .

        end if;

       selectquery := 'select "PhoneNo1",'||str||', count(*) AS "Total-Calls"
        , sum("Duration") AS "Total-Duration"
        , count("TypeOfCall" = 'CALL-IN'  OR NULL) AS "Call-In"
        , count("TypeOfCall" = 'CALL-OUT' OR NULL) AS "Call-Out"
        , count("TypeOfCall" = 'SMS-IN'   OR NULL) AS "SMS-In"
        , count("TypeOfCall" = 'SMS-OUT'  OR NULL) AS "SMS-Out"
        , min("CallDate") AS "First-Call-Date"
        , max("CallDate") AS "Last-Call-Date"
        , (max("CallDate")-min("CallDate")) AS "Days"
        ,'||additionalcolumn|| 
           ' from '||relationname
        group by grp;

--Query "selectquery" execution
return query execute selectquery;

end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

--Function calling

```
select * from function1("PhoneNo2","table1") 
as ("PhoneNo1" varchar(20),"PhoneNo2" varchar(20), "Total-Calls" bigint,
"Total-Duration" bigint,"Call-In" bigint,"Call-Out" bigint, "SMS-In" bigint,
"SMS-Out" bigint,"First-Call-Date" date,"Last-Call-Date" date, "Days" bigint,
"Tower" varchar,"State" varchar,"Country" varchar);
```

--Error occurred

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 46:    ', "count("TypeOfCall" = 'CALL-IN'  OR NULL) AS "Call-In"...
```

Comment: Does your query work when you replace variables with actual values and try to run it directly (not wrapped in function)?

Comment: Yes and it also work when i remove "||" operator and use execute format.

Comment: Even SO syntax highlight shows the error: you use `'` inside another single-quoted string literal. escape it like `''` - or use dollar quoted strings.

Comment: @pozs, Exactly right.

Comment: @pozs, For "group by" i have to include in single quote?

Comment: Your group by should be part of the `selectquery` variable: `... '||relationname||'group by '||grp;` - but yes, quoting always good idea http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE

Comment: @pozs, Thank You so much for your assistance. Is there any alternative to call function without column definition list.

Comment: If your function returns fix columns, you can define those while creating the function, see `RETURNS TABLE` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: @pozs, Yes! thats right. But my columns will be dynamic, as i am passing it to function as a parameter.

Comment: Column names does not matter. Only the column count & each column's type matters. But if the function can return with possibly different result set types, you can only use `returns setof record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1(columnname text, relationname regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
DECLARE
    str text;
    additionalcolumn text;
    grp text;
    selectquery text;
BEGIN
   --IF condition to check "columnname" for first condition.
   IF columnname = 'PhoneNo2' then
         str := ', "PhoneNo2"';                 -- double-quote
         additionalcolumn := 
               ', max("Tower") AS t, max("State") AS s, max("Country2") AS c';
         grp :='1, 2';              -- simpler with positional parameters
   ELSE                                         -- can't have NULL values 
         str := '';
         additionalcolumn := '';
         grp :='1'; 
   END IF;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE         -- use dollar quoting to allow single quotes
   'select "PhoneNo1"' || str || $$, count(*) AS "Total-Calls"
    , sum("Duration") AS "Total-Duration"
    , count("TypeOfCall" = 'CALL-IN'  OR NULL) AS "Call-In"
    , count("TypeOfCall" = 'CALL-OUT' OR NULL) AS "Call-Out"
    , count("TypeOfCall" = 'SMS-IN'   OR NULL) AS "SMS-In"
    , count("TypeOfCall" = 'SMS-OUT'  OR NULL) AS "SMS-Out"
    , min("CallDate") AS "First-Call-Date"
    , max("CallDate") AS "Last-Call-Date"
    , max("CallDate") - min("CallDate") AS "Days" 
  $$ || additionalcolumn || '
   from ' || relationname || '
   group by ' || grp;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are too many errors and problems to explain them all. Compare to your original to see what I changed. Search for related answers with the tag [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql). Detailed explanation for each and every problem here has been posted in related answers.

Your life would be much easier with [legal, lower-case identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).